# How do I Link Components correctly using React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React and React Router to try and link my components together for a project. I would like to link off a picture from the Home page (current component) to a different component.

Currently I can click the picture and it kind of acts like a link (turns blue after I click it sometimes), although it doesn't link to the other component, no errors show and nothing changes in the url bar. Nothing literally happens.

Any thoughts? Here is my code:

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route,} from 'react-router-dom';


import Header from './Header'
import PortfolioWorkPage from './Pages/PortfolioWorkPage';


class Home extends React.Component {




  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
      <Header />
      <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
      <div className="portfolioPic">
            <img src='IMAGES/Portfolio-Pics-Logo.jpg' className='portfolioPic'></img>
      <Route path='Portfolio' component={PortfolioWorkPage} />
      </div>
      </Router>

    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

Code with error:  react-dom.development.js:17117 The above error occurred in the  component: in img (created by Home) in div (created by Home) in Router (created by HashRouter) in HashRouter (created by Home) in Home (created by App) in Router (created by HashRouter) in HashRouter (created by App) in App

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


import Header from './Header'
import PortfolioWorkPage from './Pages/PortfolioWorkPage';


class Home extends React.Component {




  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
      <Header />
      <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
      <div className="portfolioPic">
            <img src='IMAGES/Portfolio-Pics-Logo.jpg' className='portfolioPic'>
            <Route exact path='Portfolio'><PortfolioWorkPage /></Route>
            </img>
             </div> 
      </Router>

    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments, here are two implementations using internal state and then a route. In the first you stay at the url path `mywebsite.com`, in the second the url path becomes `mywebsite.com/portfolio`. In both cases the image will remain on the page - you are not actually being transferred to a new page, you are just selectively rendering componenets based on the path.

Using internal state:

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     portfolioActive: false
    }
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({portfolioActive: !this.state.portfolioActive})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <>
      <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
      <div className="portfolioPic">
        <img src='IMAGES/Portfolio-Pics-Logo.jpg' className='portfolioPic' 
         onClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
      {this.state.portfolioActive ? <PortfolioWorkPage/> : null}
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

Using a route:

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Home extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
        <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
        <div className="portfolioPic">
          <Link to="/portfolio">
            <img src='IMAGES/Portfolio-Pics-Logo.jpg' className='portfolioPic'/>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <Route exact path="/portfolio">
          <PortfolioWorkPage />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: neither of these worked. First one came up with portfolioActive is not defined and I can't see anything.

The second one bundles correctly, although nothing happens when you click on the picture.

Comment: Sorry, it should be this.state.portfolioActive, I have updated the first one. Will have a look at the second one now but it should be valid.

Comment: nope, the first one still doesn't work. It does exactly the same as the bottom one now. Bundles correctly although doesn't link to the component when clicked.

Comment: I made a small adjustment to the first one `const handleClick` should just be `handleClick` - both of these now work on my machine with simple components, so I can only assume that it is something to do with your configuration or the contents of `PortfolioWorkPage` that makes it invalid.

Comment: Yup, with react it wasn't accepting the const so I got rid of it as well and still wasn't linking. It could be! I could link you the git repo if you wanted to have a look? Not sure what in there would be causing the issue though.

Comment: I got it working! I had a component called Portfolio that had the contents of the image and then just changed the code slightly to this:
`<Link to='/portfolio'>
            <Portfolio />
          </Link>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Link` or `NavLink` component provided by react router.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to="/some-url"/>
```

```
<Router>
  <div>
   <Route exact path="/some-url">
     <MyComponentWithImage />
   </Route>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: Can this be done to link to a component rather than a url page?

Comment: Not using the `Link` or `NavLink`. However, you can set up a component to render based on the url. See updated answer

Comment: I am getting this error now when I do that and wrap the route in an img tag:

react-dom.development.js:17117 The above error occurred in the <img> component:
    in img (created by Home)
    in div (created by Home)
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (created by Home)
    in Home (created by App)
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (created by App)
    in App

Comment: updated code on question to show you what I had done.

Comment: Img tags are self-closing, you can't wrap another element with them.

Comment: Is there a way to link from when you click on a picture to then go to a component?

Comment: I think you're trying to use React Router in a case where simple state management would make more sense. You use a router when you want to control the content of the page based on the url path - if you just want to update what components are showing at the current path then you control them with internal state.

Comment: Awesome, I will look into doing that instead. Many thanks :)